# Empty space still visible after hiding panel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I use Netbean 8 and I hide Jpanel with this code

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

    jPanel3.setVisible(false);
    jPanel4.setVisible(false);
}
```

but I still have empty space because of the hidden element. Below is what I'm trying to achieve. When I select radio button the hidden element will be shown and the frame will expand downward.
[image]

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you invoke revalidate() and repaint() on the parent panel. It also depends on the layout manager being used. Some layout manager respect the visibility, other don't. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanna `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 150);` on Change event where you evaluate the checked status:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Student");
checkBox.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
       System.out.println("Checked? " + checkBox.isSelected());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe how easy it was. Using `pack()` method will automatically resizes the JFrame based on the size of the components. So I just add `pack()` to my code:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    jPanel3.setVisible(false);
    jPanel4.setVisible(false);

    pack();
}
```

and it works.

Comment: You should accept your answer if it worked for you